# Is it possible to logon to a virtual machine from host machine by using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I want to create a PowerShell script to automatically logon to Windows on virtual machine(Hyper-V) after it turned on. I have been searching on the internet for the whole day but haven't found anything useful yet.

Is it possible to do this using PowerShell?

**Update**
Bundled logon app doesn't work because I want to create numbers of virtual machines on the fly.

Comment: What drives the requirement to use powershell? What's wrong with the standard auto-logon facilities? Etc this http://www.howtogeek.com/112919/how-to-make-your-windows-8-computer-logon-automatically/ and similar?

Comment: @zespri Because I want to setup numbers of new virtual machines and it's not practical to create a new virtual machine and logon every single one to set this up.

Comment: @Anonymous You don't have to interactively login to a VM to set up auto-logon. Auto-logon is just a registry setting. You can set registry settings as part of Windows setup (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766314(v=ws.10).aspx) or remotely (REG command can specify a remote machine.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with powershell. On the host powershell is used to configure and manage your VM, this API is not suitable for logging users on. On the guest you can't in any practical for you question sense run powershell before you logged in.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do after you logon. Windows supports local interactive logons, remote interactive logons, and remote logon in via various services (SMB, HTTP, and more). Logon by itself doesn't do anything, so to answer your question, it's necessary to know what you want to do after you logon.

If you just want a local interactive session, then the way to go is to use auto-logon like Zespri suggested and I elaborated on. It you want remote interactive logon, then you can script Remote Desktop (ie pass parameters to MSTSC.EXE). If you want some sort of non-interactive remote (SMB, HTTP, WSMAN/WMI, etc.), then you'd script an appropriate command line interface (NET.EXE, PS along with appropriate HTTP classes, winrm, etc.)